# mix opengl with cocos2d have error

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I create a CCNode subclass and override the draw function use my own opengles2.0 code,but it always have a error in log output:"OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCSprite draw] 530",what is more, when I add the subclass instance to the scene, other layer will not show, and the Z order in function(addChild:child z:child.zOrder tag:child.tag) also does not work. here is the subclass code:(I used the default cocos2d template to create a HelloWorld project, add add a CCNode subclass called MyNode,also create two shader )

```
//shaderf.glsl fragmentShader 
precision mediump float;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor=vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);
}



//shaderv.glsl  //vertexShader
attribute vec4 vPosition;
 void main(void)
 {
    gl_Position=vPosition;
 }

MyNode.h
@interface MyNode : CCNode {
    GLuint _programeHandle;
    GLuint _positionSlot;
}
@end

MyNode.m
@implementation MyNode
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)DrawOpengl
{
    NSString * vertexShaderPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shaderv" ofType:@"glsl"];
    NSString * fragmentShaderPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"shaderf" ofType:@"glsl"];
    GLuint vertexShader=[ZZZGLESUtils loadShader:GL_VERTEX_SHADER withFilePath:vertexShaderPath];
    GLuint fragmentShader=[ZZZGLESUtils loadShader:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER withFilePath:fragmentShaderPath];
    _programeHandle=glCreateProgram();
    if (!_programeHandle) {
        NSLog(@"failed to created programe");
        return;
    }
    glAttachShader(_programeHandle, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(_programeHandle, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(_programeHandle);
    GLint linked;
    glGetProgramiv(_programeHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
    if (!linked) {
        GLint infolen=0;
        glGetProgramiv(_programeHandle, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infolen);
        if(infolen>1)
        {
            char * infomsg=malloc(sizeof(char)*infolen);
            glGetProgramInfoLog(_programeHandle, infolen, NULL, infomsg);
            NSLog(@"Link programe error is: \n%s\n",infomsg);
            free(infomsg);
        }
        glDeleteProgram(_programeHandle);
        _programeHandle=0;
        return;
    }
    glUseProgram(_programeHandle);
    _positionSlot=glGetAttribLocation(_programeHandle, "vPosition");
}
-(void)DrawTriCone
{
    float victex[]={ 0.5,0.5,0.0,
        0.5,-0.5,0.0,
        -0.5,-0.5,0.0,
        -0.5,0.5,0.0,
        0.0,0.0,-0.7,};
    GLubyte indicx[]={
        0,1,1,2,2,3,3,0,
        4,0,4,1,4,2,4,3,
    };
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, victex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, sizeof(indicx)/sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indicx);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot);
}
- (void) draw {
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color );
    [self DrawOpengl];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0,size.width/2,size.height/2);

    [self DrawTriCone];
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
@end


below is the code in HelloWorldLayer:
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super's" return value
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        // create and initialize a Label
        CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hello World" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];

        // ask director for the window size
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        // position the label on the center of the screen
        label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );

        // add the label as a child to this Layer
        [self addChild:label];

        CCSprite *testsprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grass.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600)];
        [self addChild:testsprite];
    MyNode *myNode =[MyNode node];
        myNode.position=ccp(size.width /2 , size.height/2);
        [self addChild:myNode];
}
return self
}
```

Comment: try loading the shader the cocos way, using CCGLProgram. Check how CCSprite does it. Besides that, reduce your code to the absolute minimum to try to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thank you!! I have done it. I just to reuse the cocos2d provided value